# udisks SMART / APM stopped working?

Tags: smartctl, udisks, gnome-disks

I have a laptop with the accursed Western Digital hard drive.  I have used SMART to look at Load/Unload cycles (`smartctl -a|grep Load`).  They increase too fast towards the 300,000 lifetime limit.

I use GNOME Disks to change the hard drive APM to 254, and they stop increasing.  This wasn't a solution on its own: I also had to create `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/harddrive.sh` which does `systemctl restart udisks2` - to handle resume from suspend, when this drive settings is lost.

But some months later, I noticed the drive was clicking again and indeed Load/Unload were increasing.  What went wrong?

Also I went to look in GNOME Disks.  I can no longer find either SMART data, nor the drive APM setting!  What happened?!

I have no SELinux alerts in SELinux Troubleshooter.

```
$ rpm -q gnome-disk-utility
gnome-disk-utility-3.22.1-1.fc25.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/libexec/udisks2/udisksd
storaged-2.6.2-2.fc25.x86_64
$ systemctl status udisks2
● udisks2.service - Disk Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/udisks2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-02-23 14:10:47 GMT; 3min 55s ago
     Docs: man:udisks(8)
 Main PID: 6416 (udisksd)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/udisks2.service
           └─6416 /usr/libexec/udisks2/udisksd --no-debug

Feb 23 14:10:47 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Feb 23 14:10:47 alan-laptop udisksd[6416]: udisks daemon version 2.6.2 starting
Feb 23 14:10:47 alan-laptop udisksd[6416]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Feb 23 14:10:47 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.

$ journalctl -b |grep udisks.*sda
Feb 21 09:05:42 alan-laptop udisksd[870]: Applying configuration from /etc/udisks2/WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y.conf to /dev/sda
Feb 21 09:05:42 alan-laptop udisksd[870]: Set APM level to 254 on /dev/sda [WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y]
Feb 21 10:20:56 alan-laptop udisksd[3449]: Applying configuration from /etc/udisks2/WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y.conf to /dev/sda
Feb 21 10:20:56 alan-laptop udisksd[3449]: Set APM level to 254 on /dev/sda [WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y]
...
Feb 23 10:07:16 alan-laptop udisksd[15542]: Applying configuration from /etc/udisks2/WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y.conf to /dev/sda
Feb 23 10:07:17 alan-laptop udisksd[15542]: Set APM level to 254 on /dev/sda [WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y]
Feb 23 12:31:36 alan-laptop udisksd[4243]: Applying configuration from /etc/udisks2/WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y.conf to /dev/sda
Feb 23 12:31:36 alan-laptop udisksd[4243]: Set APM level to 254 on /dev/sda [WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y]
$ date
Thu 23 Feb 14:25:05 GMT 2017
```

My particular workaround for the suspend problem is not effective right now.  The configuration was not applied when it resumed at this time:

```
Feb 23 13:02:55 alan-laptop systemd-sleep[4238]: System resumed.
```

This is despite udisks being started at this time:

```
Feb 23 13:02:55 alan-laptop udisksd[4357]: udisks daemon version 2.6.2 starting
Feb 23 13:02:55 alan-laptop udisksd[4357]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
```

Some version of storaged (udisks) is [supposed to be re-applying the setting on resume](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/72), but that doesn't seem to be the case on my system.  I tried disabling my script in case it broke something, but again, after resume from suspend, `hdparm -B /dev/sda` shows `128`.

Comment: Did you change the [idle3](http://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/) timer?

Comment: @dirkt Notice these events break udisks significantly, the disappearing SMART seems to be just one other example.  FWIW, I'm too scared of **WARNING : THIS SOFTWARE IS EXPERIMENTAL AND NOT WELL TESTED. IT ACCESSES LOW LEVEL INFORMATION OF YOUR HARDDRIVE. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.**

Comment: I have a green WD HDD, I set the idle3 timer and no more problems. Of course it's at your own risk - but between wearing out the head load mechanism, and risking to use low-level protocols which *probably* work, the decision was easy. :-) I have disabled `udisks` (several times, this software is like a zombie) however, and wasn't experiencing any problems, so I didn't even notice the issue for a long time. Raw load cycle count is 2110770, drive still working (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging out and rebooting resolved both problems.  SMART & APM show up in GNOME Disks.  After re-enabling my resume script, the drive APM setting is re-set to 254 after resume from sleep.

There was surely some state cleared by the reboot, which was not cleared by restarting udisks.

This happened a second time, and I noticed the udev errors below at the point where udisks stopped working.

Running `sudo udevadm trigger /dev/sda` allowed udev to rescan the disks, and got udisks working again without having to reboot.  Running `udevadm info /dev/sda` before the trigger showed it was missing the attributes which udisks must be using ([diff](https://gist.github.com/sourcejedi/cba66cece464d1402a49160c157aebe4)).

The udev events are timing out because udev is counting the time spent suspended.  I have filed a [bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5903) with the specific details.

A udev event is triggered at suspend time for sda, because the hook I added to restart udisks also runs at suspend time.  It sets the APM value for the device, which requires opening it (and then closing it).  Udev change events are generated whenever a block device is closed, so that the block device will be rescanned after running a utility like fdisk or mke2fs.

---

```
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 42
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop kernel: done.
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=mlocate-upda
tedb comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop bluetoothd[865]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.177 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1173]: Window manager warning: Failed to set power save mode for output eDP-1: Permission denied
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-logind[876]: Lid opened.
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop bluetoothd[865]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.177 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd[1096]: Time has been changed
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop bluetoothd[865]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5075 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5' killed
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop bluetoothd[865]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5073 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3' is taking a 
long time
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=6695 comm="
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" 
error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoot
hd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5072 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2' is taking a 
long time
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=6695 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoot
hd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5074 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda4' killed
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=6695 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5073 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3' killed
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=6695 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5072 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2' killed
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.46" (uid=1001 pid=1704 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5074 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda4' is taking a long time
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.46" (uid=1001 pid=1704 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[634]: seq 5075 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5' is taking a long time
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop dbus-daemon[866]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.46" (uid=1001 pid=1704 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="system_u:system_r:bluetooth_t:s0")
Feb 23 08:21:05 alan-laptop systemd[1560]: Time has been changed
```

---

```
May 01 14:53:27 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May 01 14:53:27 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Stopping Disk Manager...
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
May 01 14:53:27 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Stopped Disk Manager.
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop chronyd[937]: Source 85.199.214.100 offline
May 01 14:53:27 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop chronyd[937]: Source 85.199.214.98 offline
May 01 14:53:28 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop chronyd[937]: Source 193.150.34.2 offline
May 01 14:53:28 alan-laptop systemd-sleep[31584]: Suspending system...
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop chronyd[937]: Source 85.199.214.101 offline
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Time has been changed
May 01 14:53:24 alan-laptop chronyd[937]: Can't synchronise: no selectable sources
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd-logind[877]: Lid opened.
May 01 14:53:25 alan-laptop wpa_supplicant[1103]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[639]: seq 5485 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda' killed
May 01 14:53:26 alan-laptop wpa_supplicant[1103]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd[1578]: Time has been changed
May 01 14:53:27 alan-laptop udisksd[31589]: udisks daemon version 2.6.2 starting
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[639]: seq 5485 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda' is taking a long 
May 01 14:53:28 alan-laptop udisksd[31589]: Applying configuration from /etc/udisks2/WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y.conf to /dev/sda
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd[7053]: Time has been changed
May 01 14:53:28 alan-laptop udisksd[31589]: Set APM level to 254 on /dev/sda [WDC-WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0-WX71A958AN1Y]
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[639]: worker [31598] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
May 01 14:53:28 alan-laptop udisksd[31589]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
May 01 15:19:01 alan-laptop systemd-udevd[639]: worker [31598] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/
```